# JQuery $.when with ajax array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get `$.when` to work with my code. the case is that i have a method that fires alot of Ajax requests, and i want to show a loading screeen for the user while the requests rune. The when is so i can hide it after. Given what i have learned about `$.when` should the following code work, but the when function is never fired.

```
self.createTaggingDialog(self);
var ajaxArray = new Array();
self.containers.each(function () {
    var ImageClass = $(this).ImageTags();
    if (ImageClass != null) {
        ajaxArray.push(ImageClass.TagUser(ImageClass, username));
    }
});
$.when(ajaxArray, function () {
    console.log("DONE!");
    self.RemoveTagggingDialog(self);
});
```

Here is a value of the `ajaxArray` when it reaches the $.when
[image]

The TagUser:

```
TagUser(self: ImageTags, username: string) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: self.options.UrlTagUser,
        data: {
            username: username,
            imageid: self.options.ImageId
        },
        success: function (data: UserAddJson) {
            if (data.Successful) {
                if (self.AddUserElement != null) {
                    self.AddUserElement.find('input').val('');
                    self.AddUserElement.modal('hide');
                }
                self.TagUserSuccess(self, data);
            } else {
                self.TagUserError(self, data.Message);
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            self.TagUserError(self, "");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I assume `self.containers.each` is not asynchronous, then why do you need a `jQuery.when` that is typically used for deferreds? Just put your code from a callback below looping through a collection...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$.when.apply($, ajaxArray).done(function () {
    console.log("DONE!");
    self.RemoveTagggingDialog(self);
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you pass `$` as context instead of `window`?

Comment: @m90 Yes might have to

Comment: @m90 this sample http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qJ6fY/ seems to be working with `window` as the first param

Comment: This workes, but now the fucntion is fired instantly, it dose not wait for the ajax request to finish

Comment: @DoomStone what is returned by ImageClass.TagUser(ImageClass, username)

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have added the Tag use to my first post

Comment: @m90 the (current) implementation of `.when` doesn't care what context it's passed.